# Set const int member variable outside the class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, oop

Let's say this is in Foo.h:

```
class Foo {
    private:
        const int MAXIMUM;
}
```

How do I initialize MAXIMUM to a certain value (100 in this case) in the Foo.cpp file? I tried

```
Foo::Foo() {
    MAXIMUM = 100;
}
```

and got the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". Then I tried

```
const int Foo::MAXIMUM = 100;
```

and got the error "a nonstatic data member may not be defined outside its class". And that basically answers my question as "it's just not possible" but that just means my university messed up on the header file. So, is this possible or not?

Note: This is a university assignment, so I can't change the header file. I assume the logical solution would be to set MAXIMUM to 100 in the header file.

Comment: is the MAXIMUM known before the program starts running?

Comment: http://www.drdobbs.com/the-problem-with-const-data-members/184403306

Comment: [something I wrote a little while ago about this kind of thing](https://medium.com/@ryanhaining/c-antipatterns-the-java-constructor-and-final-vs-const-make-clean-make-on-wordpress-com-fb5d73b15593)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialise const variables in two ways

In line initialisation

```
class Foo {
    private:
        const int MAXIMUM = 100;
};
```

Using initialisation list

```
class Foo {
    Foo() 
    : MAXIMUM(100) {
    }

    Foo(const int MAXIMUM) 
    : MAXIMUM(MAXIMUM) {
    }

    private:
        const int MAXIMUM;
}
```

In the below stat`enter code here`ement

```
Foo::Foo() {
    MAXIMUM = 100;
}
```

`MAXIMUM` is already created and you are trying to modify its value, which is not allowed for `const` variables.

In the below statement

```
const int Foo::MAXIMUM = 100;
```

`MAXIMUM` is not a static variable, so it will be bind with an object. You cannot access `MAXIMUM` using class name.

Comment: The second example shouldn't have inline initialization.

Comment: @bk2dcradle, thanks updated the sample code. copy paste error :)

Answer (score 1):

You want an *initializer list*:

```
Foo::Foo() : MAXIMUM(100)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"**Const**" and "**Reference**" variables are need to be initialized before class object is created. In your case,

```
Foo::Foo() {            // **End of this line, object is getting created.**
    MAXIMUM = 100;      // *This line, gets Error: "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"*
    }
```

to avoid this, you must use "Initialization list" where the value is assigned to variable before class constructor creates object.

**Fix**:

```
     Foo::Foo():MAXIMUM(100) {    // const variable is initialized 
         MAXIMUM = 200;    
     }
```